# Extra characters turning up in hashed password

Tags: php, hash, passwords, sha1

Using the PassHash class as described [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-hash-functions-and-keeping-passwords-safe/comment-page-2/), I am running into trouble when checking login details against an exiting hash.

```
class PassHash { 

private static $algo = '$2a'; 
private static $cost = '$10';  

public static function unique_salt() {  
    return substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);  
}  

public static function hash($password) {  
    return crypt($password,  
    self::$algo .  
    self::$cost .  
    '$' . self::unique_salt());
}  

public static function check_password($hash, $password) { 
    $full_salt = substr($hash, 0, 29); 
    $new_hash = crypt($password, $full_salt); 

    //echoing values for comparison's sake
    echo 'Full Salt '.$full_salt.'<br/>';
    echo 'password '.$password.'<br/>';
    echo 'New Hash '.$new_hash.'<br/>';
    echo 'Hash '.$hash.'<br/>';

    return ($hash == $new_hash);  
}  

}
```

Using the above to register the example password `passmark` results in a stored hash of 
`$2a$10$0cc127859c17132050924uI2.10wlIVA.7XwrFtMJdx`.

When trying to compare an inputted login however, the same password is hashed as `$2a$10$0cc127859c17132050924uI2.10wlIVA.7XwrFtMJdxCXjoQYEt8S`,
 where the extra characters `CXjoQYEt8S` are appended, resulting in a failed attempt.

Why would this happen?

Comment: Is the info being stored in a database?  If so is the column were it is stored able to accept that length of string?

Comment: @Pwner Oh my frigging GOD. Submit it as an answer, and I'll accept it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you the table column is able to accept a string of that length.